# How to run a process in loop and wait for it to complete and then run it again in C# without freezing GUI

Tags: c#, loops, user-interface, command-line, process

I an new to C# programming and there is a code in which I want to run a command-line process several times in a loop. I also want to wait for the command-line process to complete and then run it again with different arguments. What I did was I defined that process in a loop and everything works fine. However I also want to update Progress Bar on GUI each time the process is ended, but eventually the Process.WaitForExit() hangs out my GUI and it doesnot update progress bar. The progress bar is updated when the for loop is completed. Please help me out, here is what I've been trying to do.

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfox = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfox.CreateNoWindow = false;
processInfox.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfox.FileName = programPath;
processInfox.CreateNoWindow = true;

int startFrames = Convert.ToInt16(txtStartFrame.Text);
int endFrames = Convert.ToInt16(txtEndFrame.Text);

for (int i = startFrames; i <= endFrames; i++)
{
    progressBar1.Value = (i / endFrames) * 100;
    iName = fileFrames + "_" + i + ".jpg";
    oName = outFrames + "\\" + outFileName + "_processed_" + i + ".jpg" ; 
    processInfox.Arguments = "-i \"" + iName + "\"" + progArgs + " -o \"" + oName + "\"";
    using (Process processFire = Process.Start(processInfox))
    {
        processFire.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the loop in some function (let's call it `foo`) and use `await Task.Run(foo)` to run the code that runs the process in a background thread while not blocking the GUI thread.

[async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

[Task.Run()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

1. The Process exposes an event called [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1), you can subscribe on that. Don't forget to set the `EnableRaisingEvents` property to `true`. The subscription should be done prior the process `Start`.
2. A Process can be frozen, so the exit will never fire. In order overcome this issue you can use **timeout & kill pattern**. [WaitForExit accepts an int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_WaitForExit_System_Int32_), which is the timeout in milliseconds. Then you have to check the [HasExited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited?view=netcore-3.1) property, if it is `false` then call the [Kill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=netcore-3.1) method  .
3. Depending on your requirements you can use a background thread to span off a process. You can use a `new Thread` or use the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or use the `Task.Run` or ...